# Topological Hall Effect vs. Anomalous Hall Effect

Tags: condensed-matter, hall-effect

Is the Topological Hall Effect just another name for the Anomalous Hall Effect in a system that isn't ferromagnetic? That is, will some papers refer to this phenomena as "Topological Hall Effect" while others refer to it as "Anomalous Hall Effect"?  If so, which of these terms is more 'correct' these days?

Or, if are they are distinct phenomena, what distinguishes them?

Comment: Explained here:  https://sundoc.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/diss-online/07/07H039/t8.pdf

Comment: This very paper, in combination with other papers that speak of the anamolous hall effect in non-ferromagnetic materials (e.g https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02358) are what prompted this question. Are these two papers talking about the same phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my sense, "topological Hall effect" is often used in the context of "Anomalous Hall effect with real space Berry curvature". So, the Hall effect in spin non-collinear spin texture such as magnetic skyrmion or specific antiferromagnet(https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.174432).

On the other hand, Hall effects caused by k-space Berry curvature (band structure) (or scattering (skew scattering and side jump)) is called anomalous Hall effect. This term is used in both ferromagnets and antiferromagnets. For anomalous Hall effect in antiferromagnet, see https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05756-7.pdf?origin=ppub